# Why does my code not realize that game = false?

Tags: python, variables, boolean

I have a while loop that says:

```
game = True
while game == True:
    shop = False
    while shop == False:
        choice = input("Press ENTER to dig. Press E(then ENTER) to end game. Press S(then enter) for shop.")
        if choice == "E" or choice == "e":
           game = False
```

And yet it keeps on repeating and I cant cant figure out why (I'm also new to coding so there could be an obvious answer)
Link to code here: https://repl.it/@WeirdDragon/ore-digging-sim#main.py

Comment: You never set `shop` to True, so `while shop == False` is an infinite loop.

Comment: Because `shop` remains `False` and *that* loop keeps looping.

Comment: You never set `shop = True`, so the inner loop never stops and you never get back to the outer loop's test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break out of the inner loop so you can get back to the outer loop's test.

```
game = True
while game:
    shop = False
    while not shop:
        choice = input("Press ENTER to dig. Press E(then ENTER) to end game. Press S(then enter) for shop.")
        if choice == "E" or choice == "e":
            game = False
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `shop == True` to break from the inner while first. Then, it can realize that `game == False`

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how while loops work, take this for example:

```
a = 5
while a == 5:
    a = 6
    print('done')
```

Output:

```
 done
```

The condition we gave the while loop tells it when to stop looping, but python must first reach the condition again in order to compare, meaning as long as there is no break statement, python will first finish the current loop. But in your code, because of the other while loop in that while loop never ends, we never gave python a chace to compare that game condition.

```
game = True
while game == True:
    shop = False
    while shop == False:
        choice = input("Press ENTER to dig. Press E(then ENTER) to end game. Press S(then enter) for shop.")
        if choice == "E" or choice == "e":
           game = False
```

To fix that, simply add a break statement after the game = False:

```
        if choice == "E" or choice == "e":
           game = False
           break
```